# php foreach preg_match'd line, get next lines

Tags: php, foreach, preg-match-all

I hope the title is self explanatory.

I would like to loop over a xml file line by line, then match a particular line (getting attributes from that line), then get the next X lines after that line.

I have the following code, which attempts to do this, but I cant seem to figure out how to get the next X lines after.

```
$file = 'Electric.xml';
$lines = file($file);//file in to an array

foreach($lines as $line){

    $reads = element_attributes('WINDOW',$line);

    if($reads['class'] == 'Bracelets'){
        print_r($reads);
    }

    if($reads['class'] == 'Handbags'){
        print_r($reads);
    }
}

function element_attributes($element_name, $xml) {
    if ($xml == false) {
        return false;
    }
    // Grab the string of attributes inside an element tag.
    $found = preg_match('#<'.$element_name.
            '\s+([^>]+(?:"|\'))\s?/?>#',
            $xml, $matches);
    if ($found == 1) {
        $attribute_array = array();
        $attribute_string = $matches[1];
        // Match attribute-name attribute-value pairs.
        $found = preg_match_all(
                '#([^\s=]+)\s*=\s*(\'[^<\']*\'|"[^<"]*")#',
                $attribute_string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        if ($found != 0) {
            // Create an associative array that matches attribute
            // names to attribute values.
            foreach ($matches as $attribute) {
                $attribute_array[$attribute[1]] =
                        substr($attribute[2], 1, -1);
            }
            return $attribute_array;
        }
    }
    // Attributes either weren't found, or couldn't be extracted
    // by the regular expression.
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper parser, [like SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), to parse the file. Then your issue becomes trivial. The [PHP manual contains a tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) to help you get started.

In this case you just loop over the lines, checking the property of the tag you're looking for, until you find a match. Then, loop over the next # elements, saving them into an array.
Something like this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXML ("file.xml");
foreach ($xml->node->element as $element) {
    if ($element->attribute != "match") {
         continue;
    }

    // If we get here we want to save the next # lines/elements.
}
```

Comment: Can't use an XML parser I'm afraid. This is not well formed XML.

Comment: @Ke. Is it so bad that even DOMdocument fails..? :O In that case, I feel for you and wish you the best of luck!

Comment: Yes, its that bad! I didnt create the file. I have no choice as well, I need the data!

Comment: It's either "Proper parser" or "SimpleXML". Choose one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$linesLength = count($lines);
$XLines = array();
for($index = 0; $index < $linesLength; $index++){

    $reads = element_attributes('WINDOW',$line);

    if($reads['class'] == 'Bracelets'){
        print_r($reads);
        $XLines[] = array_slice($array, $index, $X);
        $index += $X;
    }

    if($reads['class'] == 'Handbags'){
        print_r($reads);
        $XLines[] = array_slice($array, $index, $X);
        $index += $X;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kris, there are lots of missing variables in this code. Where do XLines and $array come from ? and $X?

Comment: this code just replace your foreach clouse, and you have to define the $X. .

Comment: $XLines isnt defined, nor is $array